# Error message displayed even with valid inputs

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I was trying to validate my HTML form with the help of Javascript, but the error messages get displayed even after providing valid inputs. If I add 'preventDefault()', the error messages get displayed only with invalid inputs but the form gets submitted anyway. My code-

HTML

```
<form id="form" novalidate onsubmit="return validate()">

<label for="firstName">Enter your first name</label><br>
<input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" required><br>
<span role="alert" id="nameError" aria-hidden="true"> Please enter a valid name </span>
<label for="lastName">Enter your last name here</label><br>
<input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" required><br>
<span role="alert" id="lastNameError" aria-hidden="true"> Please enter a valid name </span> 
/*other elements in the form */
```

Javascript for error messages

```
const firstNameField = document.getElementById("firstName");
const lastNameField = document.getElementById("lastName");

let valid = true;

if (firstNameField.getAttribute(length)<3
|| firstNameField.getAttribute(pattern)!="[A-Za-z+]"
|| lastNameField.getAttribute(length)<3
|| lastNameField.getAttribute(pattern)!="[A-Za-z+]")
 {
const nameError = document.getElementById("nameError");
nameError.classList.add("visible");
firstNameField.classList.add("invalid");
nameError.setAttribute('aria-hidden', false);
nameError.setAttribute('aria-invalid', true);

const lastNameError = document.getElementById("lastNameError");
lastNameError.classList.add("visible");
lastNameField.classList.add("invalid");
lastNameError.setAttribute('aria-hidden', false);
lastNameError.setAttribute('aria-invalid', true);


valid = false;

}

return valid;
}
```

CSS for the error messages

```
#nameError, #lastNameError{
display: none;
font-size: 0.8em;
color: red;
}

#nameError.visible, #lastNameError.visible{
  display: block;
}

input.invalid {
 border-color: red;
}
```

I'm new to Javascript so any suggestions would be helpful for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of your problem is in your validation tests where you call `getAttribute()` it does not have those attributes, you want to look at the element's **value**.
You can replace those statements with ones that check that the `firstNameField.value` and the `lastNameField.value` each match a regex `/^[A-Za-z]{3}[A-Za-z]*$/` that checks for three or more characters in the set `[A-Za-z]` only. I would also recommend checking each input individually so that you are only changing what is invalid.

```js
let validate = function() {
  const firstNameField = document.getElementById("firstName");
  const lastNameField = document.getElementById("lastName");
  const pattern = /^[A-Za-z]{3}[A-Za-z]*$/;

  let valid = true;
  if (!firstNameField.value.match(pattern)) {
    const nameError = document.getElementById("nameError");
    nameError.classList.add("visible");
    firstNameField.classList.add("invalid");
    nameError.setAttribute('aria-hidden', false);
    nameError.setAttribute('aria-invalid', true);

    valid = false;

  }
  if (!lastNameField.value.match(pattern)) {

    const lastNameError = document.getElementById("lastNameError");
    lastNameError.classList.add("visible");
    lastNameField.classList.add("invalid");
    lastNameError.setAttribute('aria-hidden', false);
    lastNameError.setAttribute('aria-invalid', true);

    valid = false;

  }

  return valid;
}
```

```css
#nameError,
#lastNameError {
  display: none;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: red;
}

#nameError.visible,
#lastNameError.visible {
  display: block;
}

input.invalid {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" novalidate onsubmit="return validate()">

  <label for="firstName">Enter your first name</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" required><br>
  <span role="alert" id="nameError" aria-hidden="true"> Please enter a valid name </span>
  <label for="lastName">Enter your last name here</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" required><br>
  <span role="alert" id="lastNameError" aria-hidden="true"> Please enter a valid name </span>
  <!-- /*other elements in the form */ -->
  <button>
    submit
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks, this helped me understand the problem as well as solve it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `preventDefault()` also add, [`stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to prevent the `submit` event from bubbling up to the `form` and submitting it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing the closing bracket on your if condition.

Also try to make a runnable example with snippet [this description on stackoverflow should help](https://www.reddit.com/r/wet_pussy/comments/v5qj28/22_year_old_trixie_having_a_spa_day/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in js:

```
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {  
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('run validation here, return true or false to submit');
}
```

Comment: This will only allow for all fields to validate as the form is submitted, rather than validating as you work with them.

Comment: mb, didnt see the validate function in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

HTML Form: `

```
         <form name="" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return 
             validateForm()" method="post"> 
            Name: <input type="text" name="fname"> <input  
             type="submit" 
             value="Submit"> 
          </form>`
```

JS:

```
     function validateForm() {
       let x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
        if (x == "") {
         alert("Name must be filld out");
         return fales;
       }
     }
```